# How to make a record implement an interface?

Tags: f#

If I have an interface:

```
type IData = 
  abstract member firstName: string
  abstract member lastName: string
```

How do I define a record type that complies with this interface.

I tried something like below:

```
> type Data = { firstName: string; lastName: string } interface IData ;;


Snippet.js(43,63): error FS0366: No implementation was given for 'abstract member IData.firstName : string'. Note that all interface members must be implemented
and listed under an appropriate 'interface' declaration, e.g. 'interface ... with member ...'.
```

From the [official reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/records) for Records:

> Record fields differ from classes in that they are automatically exposed as properties

My first question is: If properties are "automatically exposed" then why do I need to "do something" to implement them.

Since the error message askes me to provide an implementation for the interface, I tried the following:

```
> type Data = { firstName: string; lastName: string; } interface IData with
-   member this.firstName with get () = this.firstName
-   member this.lastName with get () = this.lastName 

type Data =
  {firstName: string;
   lastName: string;}
  with
    interface IData
  end
```

So far so good, however now when I try to use this, I run into issues:

```
> let d: IData = { firstName = "john"; lastName = "doe" } ;;

error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'IData'
but here has type
    'Data'
```

Another Attempt:

```
> let d = { firstName = "john"; lastName = "doe" }
- ;;
val d : Data = {firstName = "john";
                lastName = "doe";}

> let d2: IData = d ;;


C:\Users\loref\Workspace\source-nly10r\Untitled-1(25,17): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'IData'
but here has type
    'Data'
```

So, my second question is that if `Data` implements `IData` then why can't I assign a value of `Data` type to a variable of `IData` type ?

Comment: That's not possible. You have to add the methods by hand. See this suggestion https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/68

Comment: But even if I do, I don't seem to be able to depend on the interface.

Comment: You need to explicitly cast. In the suggestion it seems they mixed both suggestions in one. However if you ask me I'm in favor of the first but against the second.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed by [Gustavo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446822/gustavo), implicit interface implementation is [being discussed](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/195) by F# implementers, and is not currently available.

Wrt. my second question, explicit casting is required:

```
> let d2: IData = d :> IData ;;
val d2 : IData = {firstName = "john";
                  lastName = "doe";}
```

Comment: `upcast d` would be a valid alternative to `d :> IData` in cases like this