# What is the idiomatic way for an implementation to depend on a partial record type?

Tags: f#

My intent is to define a module with functions which can operate on all records types which comply with certain assumptions about the keys.

To illustrate, let us have the following code:

```
> type DBRow = { id: string ; createdAt: System.DateTime } ;;
type DBRow =
  {id: string;
   createdAt: System.DateTime;}

> let logCreationInfo row = printf "Record %s created at %s " row.id (row.createdAt.ToString()) ;;
val logCreationInfo : row:DBRow -> unit
```

I would like to change the above `logCreationInfo` to be able to operate on all records which have `id: string` and `createdAt: System.DateTime` (and maybe other things).

Coming from typescript's structural typing, I'd have expected this to be trivial, but I am exploring the possibility that there is a more idiomatic way to handle this in F#.

I had [attempted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606250/make-a-record-implement-an-interface) to handle this using interfaces, but even if that could work, since F# supports only explicit interfaces, this will not be suitable for types I don't define myself.

Comment: SRTP is probably the easiest way to access members from different types. However you can do the above with interfaces as well. But tbh, an easier way would be greatly welcome (like Typeclasses in Scala with implicits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [statically resolved type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters).

```
let inline logCreationInfo (x : ^t) =
    printfn "Record %s created at %s" 
        (^t : (member id : string) (x))
        ((^t : (member createdAt : System.DateTime) (x)).ToString())
```

Answer (score 4):

F# largely uses nominative typing - this is a natural choice in its runtime environment, as this is what [Common Type System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/common-type-system) specification prescribes. Adherence to that set of rules allows F# code to near-seamlessly interoperate with other .NET languages.

It's worth noting that this follows the same reasoning as to why TypeScript uses structural typing. Since that language builds up on top of dynamically typed JavaScript, it's more natural to express object relationships in terms of their structure rather than nominal types - which are a foreign concept in JS.

F# does have a "backdoor" for structural typing through already mentioned SRTPs, but I would suggest using it very sparingly. SRTPs are resolved and the code using them is inlined by the compiler, making for longer compilation times and reduced interoperability with other languages and the .NET platform in general (simply put, you can't refer to that code from other languages or using reflection API, because it's "compiled away").

Usually there are other solutions available. Interfaces were already mentioned, though the example used was a bit contrived - this is simpler:

```
type IDBRow =
    abstract Id: string
    abstract CreatedAt: System.DateTime

type Person = 
    {
        id: string
        name: string
        age: int    
        createdAt: System.DateTime
    }
    interface IDBRow with
        member this.Id = this.id
        member this.CreatedAt = this.createdAt

let logCreationInfo (row: #IDBRow) = 
    printf "Record %s created at %s" row.Id (string row.CreatedAt)

let x = { id = "1"; name = "Bob"; age = 32; createdAt = DateTime.Now }
logCreationInfo x
```

Or using composition and a generic type to capture the generic part of what it means to be a DBRow:

```
type DBRow<'data> = 
    {
        id: string
        data: 'data
        createdAt: System.DateTime
    }

type Person = 
    {
        name: string
        age: int    
    }

let logCreationInfo (row: DBRow<_>) = 
    printf "Record %s created at %s" row.id (string row.createdAt)

let x = { id = "1"; data = { name = "Bob"; age = 32 }; createdAt = DateTime.Now }
logCreationInfo x
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with interfaces:

```
open System

type DBRow1 = {
    id: string
    createdAt: DateTime
}

type DBRow2 = {
    id: string
    createdAt: DateTime
    address: string
}

/// The types are defined above without an interface

let row1 = {id = "Row1"; createdAt = DateTime.Now}
let row2 = {id = "Row2"; createdAt = DateTime.Now; address = "NYC"}

type IDBRow<'A> =
    abstract member Data:(string * DateTime) 

// Object expression implements the interface
let Data1 (x:DBRow1)  = {
    new IDBRow<_> with
        member __.Data = (x.id, x.createdAt)
}

let Data2 (x: DBRow2) = {
    new IDBRow<_> with
    member __.Data = (x.id, x.createdAt)
}

//pass in both the object expression and the record
let getData (ifun: 'a -> IDBRow<'b>) xrec = 
    (ifun xrec).Data

// You could partially apply the functions: `getData1 = getData Data1` 
getData Data1 row1 //("Row1", 2018/02/05 9:24:17)
getData Data2 row2 //("Row2", 2018/02/05 9:24:17)
```

You can certainly use an interface (an object expression in this case) to tack on another member, `.Data`, even if you don'T have access to the original type. You would still need to put together one object expression for each type though, so SRTP might be a more "elegant" solution.